# Feedparser - KeyError: 'fullcount'

Tags: python, pyserial, feedparser, keyerror

I have tried to follow [this guide](http://j4mie.org/blog/how-to-make-a-physical-gmail-notifier/). It is about making a physical gmail notifier. When I entered the same code it found an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/Projects/gmailnotifier.py", line 20, in <module>
    )["feed"]["fullcount"])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\feedparser-5.1.3-py2.7.egg\feedparser.py", line 375, in __getitem__
    return dict.__getitem__(self, key)
KeyError: 'fullcount'
```

I am not sure why and thats why im asking. I am using windows 7, python 2.7.3, feedparser 5.1.3 and pyserial 2.6

Here is the full code:

```
import serial, sys, feedparser

#Settings - Change these to match your account details
USERNAME="mymain@gmail.com"
PASSWORD="mypassword"
PROTO="https://"
SERVER="mail.google.com"
PATH="/gmail/feed/atom"

SERIALPORT = "COM3" # Change this to your serial port!

# Set up serial port
try:
    ser = serial.Serial(SERIALPORT, 9600)
except serial.SerialException:
    sys.exit()

newmails = int(feedparser.parse(
    PROTO + USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD + "@" + SERVER + PATH
)["feed"]["fullcount"])

# Output data to serial port
if newmails > 0: ser.write('M')
else: ser.write('N')

# Close serial port
ser.close()
```

Comment: If you do this in the interactive Python shell, what does the result of the feedparser.parse() look like"?

Comment: I get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just took a look at that from a REPL. The code will work as-is for me. However, I was able to reproduce your error by entering an incorrect password.

This is what `feedparser.parse()['feed']` looks like if you fail to authenticate:

```
>>> feedparser.parse(PROTO + USERNAME + ":" + INCORRECT_PASSWORD + "@" + SERVER + PATH)['feed']
{'summary': u'<h1>Unauthorized</h1>\n<h2>Error 401</h2>'}
>>>
```

This is what it should look like if you do authenticate properly:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(feedparser.parse(PROTO + USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD + "@" + SERVER + PATH)['feed'])
{'fullcount': u'0',
 'link': u'http://mail.google.com/mail',
 'links': [{'href': u'http://mail.google.com/mail',
            'rel': u'alternate',
            'type': u'text/html'}],
 'subtitle': u'New messages in your Gmail Inbox',
 'subtitle_detail': {'base': u'https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom',
                     'language': None,
                     'type': u'text/plain',
                     'value': u'New messages in your Gmail Inbox'},
 'title': u'Gmail - Inbox for xxxxxxx@gmail.com',
 'title_detail': {'base': u'https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom',
                  'language': None,
                  'type': u'text/plain',
                  'value': u'Gmail - Inbox for xxxxxxx@gmail.com'},
 'updated': u'2013-03-01T20:11:03Z',
 'updated_parsed': time.struct_time(tm_year=2013, tm_mon=3, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=20, tm_min=11, tm_sec=3, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=60, tm_isdst=0)}
>>>
```

You should print out the result of `feedparser.parse()` to check if this is indeed the problem you have, but I suspect that simply making sure your username/password are correct will fix your problem

Comment: I get this error when I try your code. {'summary': u'<h1>Unauthorized</h1>\n<h2>Error 401</h2>'}. Why is that? I tried to copy my password from the code to gmails login page, it worked. So my pass and username is correct...

Comment: I don't know what's causing your problem in particular. Maybe you are using 2 factor authentication?

Comment: OKey I found the answer. I had to make a program specified password at acccounts.google.com and use that password. I should have tought about it earlier... Thank you for taking your time to help me.

Comment: Ah, so you did have 2FA on. I do too, that's why I asked :-)