# KeyError: 'fullcount' in mail script

Tags: python, parsing, email, raspberry-pi, keyerror

I wrote a Python script to check my email and turn on an LED when I have new mail.
After about 1 hour, I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "checkmail.py", line 10, in <module>
   B = int(feedparser.parse("https://" + U + ":" + P + "@mail.google.com/gmail/feed/atom")["feed"]["fullcount"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/feedparser.py", line 375, in __getitem__
    return dict.__getitem__(self, key)
KeyError: 'fullcount'
```

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164294/feedparser-keyerror-fullcount)
and didn't find an answer. Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO, feedparser, time
U = "username"
P = "password"
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
A = 23
GPIO.setup(A, GPIO.OUT)
while True:
        B = int(feedparser.parse("https://" + U + ":" + P + "@mail.google.com/gmail/feed/atom")["feed"]["fullcount"])
        if B > 0:
                GPIO.output(A, True)
        else:
                GPiO.output(A, False)
        time.sleep(60)
```

I'm running this on a Raspberry Pi.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some debug code and see what this call returns:

```
feedparser.parse("https://" + U + ":" + P + "@mail.google.com/gmail/feed/atom")["feed"]
```

It's clearly something that does not contain a "fullcount" item. You might want to do something like this:

```
feed = feedparser.parse("https://{}:{}@mail.google.com/gmail/feed/atom".format(U, P))
try:
    B = int(feed["feed"]["fullcount"])
except KeyError:
    # handle the error
    continue  # you might want to sleep or put the following code in the else block
```

That way you can deal with the error (you might want to catch `ValueError` too, in case `int()` fails because of an invalid value) without it blowing up your script.